# Stopping Heroku from building a react app, and deploying with local production build

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I want to deploy a React + Django application on Heroku.  When I push to Heroku, it automatically rebuilds my application without referring to my webpack.  Is there any way I can push my build directory directly to Heroku?

Thanks!